# MessageBox Causes MaskedTextBox Cursor Location To Move

Tags: vb.net, winforms, maskedtextbox

This has been driving me nuts for ages.  If the focus of a VB.NET app is a `MaskedTextBox`, anytime a `MessageBox` is displayed, the cursor location of the `MaskedTextBox` resets to the 2nd letter.  Why?  Any ideas how to prevent this?

Here's how to replicate:
Create a blank Winforms app, add a `MaskedTextBox`.  Set the `Mask` to ">&&&&&&-&".  Add the following code to the form:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.TextChanged
        If MaskedTextBox1.Text = "000000-" Then
            MsgBox("hi")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Run the app.  Start typing 0's into the text box.  Notice that when you hit the 6th zero and the `MsgBox` is fired, the cursor moves back to the 2nd letter.

EDIT:
This has nothing to do with the message box itself.  It seems to have something to do with any other form showing.  See this example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.TextChanged
        If MaskedTextBox1.Text = "000000-" Then
            Dim f As New Form1
            f.Show() 'after you close the new form, the cursor will have moved in the first!
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The behavior is the same for MsgBox vs MessageBox.Show.  Also, this is a MaskedTextBox, so the SelectionStart always returns 0 unless the user has text selected, which isn't the case when you're typing the 0's so the code can't return the cursor because you can't pre-detect it's location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MaskedTextBox` overrides OnTextChanged, to set some state that allows to determine later what is the actual length of the text and the mask, or a mix of the two, depending on what the Control needs to present to the user.

To keep it simple (or read what's at the bottom), you should allow the sequence of method calls generated by the event to complete, before you do something that moves the Focus somewhere else, generating a new sequence of method calls and validation events that end up compromising the registration of states in some Controls.
This applies to different events of other Controls as well.

To defer the presentation of the MessageBox, you can [BeginInvoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) it.
The code that follows is executed asynchronously, after the `TextChanged` event has completed its procedures:

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.TextChanged
    If MaskedTextBox1.IsHandleCreated AndAlso MaskedTextBox1.Text = "000000-" Then
        BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() MessageBox.Show(Me, "Some message")))
    End If
End Sub
```

If you need to handle the result of the MessageBox, do that in the same way:

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.TextChanged
    If MaskedTextBox1.IsHandleCreated AndAlso MaskedTextBox1.Text = "000000-" Then
        BeginInvoke(New Action(
            Sub()
                If MessageBox.Show(
                    Me, "Some question", "Some caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
                    ' Do something when the answer is 'Yes'
                End If
            End Sub))
End Sub
```

You can also set a Field to the result of the Dialog and inspect it somewhere else.

The same if you show a Form instead, Modal or not:

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.TextChanged
    If MaskedTextBox1.IsHandleCreated AndAlso MaskedTextBox1.Text = "000000-" Then
        BeginInvoke(New Action(
            Sub()
                Dim f As New SomeForm()
                f.Show()
            End Sub))
End Sub
```

---

If you're interested in what happens under the hood, see the [code that sets the final state](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MaskedTextBox.cs,2362) in the `OnTextChanged` override, and read the notes [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MaskedTextBox.cs,89), then see what happens when the [OnTextChanged method of the base class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,1731) is called.
You can infer what happens after, when [SetWindowText()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MaskedTextBox.cs,2908) is called for other reasons (`OnTextChange()` is also called when the mask is set back to the Control, when it's been computed what part is the text and what part is the mask)

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on Jimi's excellent answer, here's a sub you can add that safely calls msgbox while also getting the result.  Instead of calling msgbox, call safeMessage with the same arguments.

```
    Public Function safeMessage(message As String, Optional buttons As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, Optional title As String = Nothing) As MsgBoxResult
        Dim result As MsgBoxResult
        PNDecoder.frmMain.BeginInvoke(Sub() result = MsgBox(message, buttons, title))
        Return result
    End Function
```